# Sectioning macros with Plain

Tags: sectioning, plain-tex

Plain is awesome up until you'd want to make some structure for your document(s), because getting the sectioning macros right seems to be painfully difficult.

Plain comes with a single sectioning macro called `\beginsection`, but I would be interested in seeing your sectioning macro(s), or pointers to such definitions.

For you see, the problems I've had with making one are related to situations when there is a higher-level sectioning command directly followed by a lower-level sectioning command. Because normally I would indeed want there to be an allowance for page-break, but in the abovementioned case I'd certainly not want that. For clarity, by higher- and lower-level I mean a structure like (from highest to lowest):

- Chapter
- Section
- Subsection
- Subsubsection

**So the question is:** *How can I make a sectioning macro which could differentiate between if it was used just after a higher-level sectioning command, or not*

I chose not to post any example code because most of it would have nothing to do with the problem itself.

Comment: Couldn't you look at the relevant part of `texdoc source2e` to see how LaTeX does it and modify that? or would that be cheating?

Comment: @Seamus: Thanks for the tip! What do I need for that command to work? (I've tried: texdoc source2e => command not found; tlmgr install texdoc; texdoc source2e => Sorry, no documentation found for source2e.)

Comment: http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `\vskip1sp\par` at the end of a sectioning command. Then you can test this with `\ifdim\lastskip=1sp`. You can also use different numbers to check which of the commands is used. (`1sp` is so small that is has practically no effect.)

If you want to use `\noindent`, then a `\vskip` at the end would be a bad idea: use `\noindent\hskip-1sp\hskip1sp\relax` instead of the above; then again `\ifdim\lastskip=1sp` should do the job.

Comment: Why the `\par`? After the `\vskip`, you will already be in vertical mode. `\par` has (almost) no effect there.

Comment: Thank you very, very much, this seems like a perfect answer. You even went ahead and read my mind about the noindent!

Comment: @TH.: I'm actually not sure anymore. I did some testing before I posted the answer, and I guess the `\par` got in since it didn't work without it: It has the same effect as `\relax`, but probably `\relax` is better.

Comment: Could you post the definition of an example sectioning command to provide a more complete context?

Comment: @Christian: Are you asking morbusg or me? Maybe morbusg can just give you what he's using.

Comment: @Hendrik Either of you but I was commenting here because you seem to have specific ideas about sectioning commands. (I also looked at `\beginsection` in PlainTeX and noticed that none of these tricks are used there.)

Comment: @morbusg: Can you help Christian out here? I think you're the one having specific ideas about sectioning commands, not me. I only contributed some tricks.

Comment: @Christian: No, none of these tricks are used there, and this made morbusg ask here. Am I right, morbusg?

Comment: Hendrik, yes, Plain's `\beginsection` doesn't (in my understanding) incorporate this specific requirement. @Christian: you can take a look at my edit of the question which includes some of the code I had put together (you can click on the link "edited xxx time ago" to see it). I'm sure I haven't taken into account another bazillion things which might be covered by LaTeX's sectioning commands. If you'd like, I could probably put my current commands up somewhere for you.

Comment: Thanks, @morbusg. (With "Am I right" I actually meant the "this made morbusg ask here", but nevermind `:-)`)

Answer (score 3):

I am not a plain TeX user, but the easy way seem the `OPmac` package:

> [image: MWE]

```
\input opmac
\chap Example  of chapter\par  Some text 
\sec Section example\par  Some text
\secc Subsection example\par That is  all. 
\bye
```

Comment: Some reason for the downvote ?