# How do \lastskip and \ifdim work?

Tags: tex-core

I thought I knew the answer to this question, but I can't understand the following plain TeX code:

```
\noindent\hskip1pt\ifdim\lastskip=0pt lastskip was 0pt\fi\par
\noindent\hskip1pt\showthe\lastskip
\bye
```

In the first paragraph (started with `\noindent`) I put a skip of `1pt`, but the test for the last skip yields `0pt`. In the second paragraph, `\showthe` shows that the last skip was `1.0pt`. What is happening here?

(I was led to this question by trying to answer [morbusg's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8389/1235).)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are missing a `\relax` here: `\ifdim` is expandable, and so `\hskip` will keep expanding looking for a `plus`. Now, it does not find one but the test result has already been decided (`true`) *before* the `\hskip` takes place. In the second line, `\showthe` is not expandable, so `\hskip` stops and inserts the skip before `\showthe` is executed.

As Hendrik point's out in a comment, TeX will expand looking for an optional space for any dimension. Thus something like

```
\newskip\mydim
\mydim4pt\ifdim\mydim=4pt\else \ARG\fi
\showthe\mydim
\bye
```

gives a different result to

```
\newskip\mydim
\mydim4pt \ifdim\mydim=4pt\else \ARG\fi
\showthe\mydim
\bye
```

as in the later case the space terminates the assignment before the `\ifdim` test.

However, `\hskip` is a *skip* (rubber length), not a dimension. It therefore has optional stretch and shrink components in addition to the fixed length. So modifying the original code to

```
\noindent\hskip1pt \ifdim\lastskip=0pt lastskip was 0pt\fi\par
\noindent\hskip1pt \showthe\lastskip
\bye
```

does *not* change the outcome. TeX finds the optional space for `1pt` but continues to expand looking for `plus` or `minus`. So the assignment can only take place on the first line when it hits the `l`, by which time the `\ifdim` result has already been determined.

Comment: Thanks, with `\relax` it works, great! The same happens for `\kern1pt` and `\lastkern`. I guess that TeX keeps expanding looking for an optional space after `pt`. Correct?

Comment: @Hendrik. This is a glue item, so there is an optional `plus` and/or `minus` to check for.

Comment: @Joseph: The optional `plus` or `minus` can only come _before_ the number `1`, or am I mistaken? I've had a look at the TeXbook. On page 270 it says <unit of measure> −-> <optional spaces><internal unit>
| <optional true><physical unit><one optional space>. So now I'm pretty sure it's the one optional space after the physical unit `pt`.

Comment: @Hendrik. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks for the confirmation! (I totally misread your comment. I thought of an optional `+` (or `--`) that could come before the number `1`, not about the optional `plus` and `minus` (which I do know, so I perfectly understood the first version of your answer, and somehow didn't expect you'd point those `plus` and `minus` out again).

Comment: @Hendrik. In the long-term it's probably best to have this explicit in the answer it helps less-experienced people follow what's going on.

Comment: @Joseph: Maybe we're talking at cross-purposes. I perfectly understood your original answer, but the edited answer is even better; I fully agree that it's better to have that in the answer. I just wanted to explain my confusion about `plus` versus `+`.

Comment: @Hendrik. I did wonder a bit what you were getting at: `+` never occurred to me at all :-)

Comment: @Joseph: I think in your first comment you were also a bit confused `:-)` `\kern` wants to see a `dimen`, which doesn't take stretch or shrink. And I didn't realize that you didn't realize that.