# Unexpected conditional branch with \ifdim

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, plain-tex

I have a problem with the following code:

```
\newtoks\sectoks
\sectoks={\noindent}

\newtoks\subsubjectstyle
\subsubjectstyle={\emitsectglue 1\the\sectoks}

\newtoks\postsectoks
\postsectoks={\par\smallskip\noindent\kern-1sp\hskip1sp}

\long\def\subsubject#1\par{%
  {\the\subsubjectstyle#1}\the\postsectoks}

\def\emitsectglue#1{%
  \ifdim\lastskip=1sp
    \nobreak
  \else
    \vskip0pt plus#1\baselineskip
    \penalty-\numexpr#1*100+50\relax
    \vskip0pt plus-#1\baselineskip
    \vskip#1\baselineskip
  \fi}

\long\def\blockquote#1\eol{%
  \emitsectglue 1
  \begingroup
    \raggedright\narrower\noindent #1
    \smallskip
  \endgroup\noindent}

\tracingall

\subsubject
  The following subsubject will choose the first if's true-branch.

\subsubject
  But the following blockquote will not. Why is that?

\blockquote
  Be conservative in what you send, liberal in what you receive
\eol

\bye
```

When using the `\subsubject` command followed by another `\subsubject`, the macros work as expected and do not add the vertical glue & negative penalty.

However, when using the exact same code with another command, all of a sudden the right `\if`-branch doesn't get selected.  I don't understand why is that.

Comment: Could you think of a better question title? _Problem with X_ titles tend to be not the best titles ...

Comment: @doncherry: You're right, the title isn't good. But I'm having trouble coming up with something descriptive. Would you have a suggestion?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. This question generally is too hardcore-TeX-y for me to understand. How about _Plain-TeX \if doesn't work as expected_? But perhaps @egreg can come up with an even better title?

Comment: That italic backslash looks funny `:)`

Comment: @doncherry: hmm, `\if` is a TeX primitive, not plain-tex IIRC, so maybe this title is better?

Comment: This title is surely better. I don't think that the way you're coping with this problem, that is forcing horizontal mode, is the best possible.

Comment: @morbusg: That's why I said "not really" `:)`. I hardly know anything about TeX. But yes, this title is better, thanks!

Comment: @egreg: Oh, I forgot to mention in the question that suggestions on improving the code are most welcome as well! As it stands, the code has worked rather well for me (it was based on [Hendrik Vogt's earlier answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8390/1410)), it's just these kinds of edge cases (blockquote right after heading) that bite me once in a while.

Comment: Hendrik Vogt's answer had `\hskip1sp\relax`. :-)

Comment: @egreg: :-O I must've dropped it at some point for some reason. Note to self: always make a comment in the code *why* something is there, so there won't be a temptation to remove it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\relax` after `\hskip1sp`: TeX expands tokens when looking for a skip specification and, when `\blockquote` follows, the specification is not yet complete, so the expansion evaluates `\ifdim` before the skip is inserted.

If `\subsubject` follows, there is no problem, because the first token in the replacement text is `{` which stops expansion.

I would brace the argument to `\emitsecglue` and get rid of a couple of possible spurious space sources:

```
\newtoks\sectoks
\sectoks={\noindent}

\newtoks\subsubjectstyle
\subsubjectstyle={\emitsectglue{1}\the\sectoks}

\newtoks\postsectoks
\postsectoks={\par\smallskip\noindent\kern-1sp\hskip1sp\relax}

\def\subsubject#1\par{%
  {\the\subsubjectstyle#1}\the\postsectoks}

\def\emitsectglue#1{%
  \ifdim\lastskip=1sp
    \nobreak
  \else
    \vskip0pt plus#1\baselineskip
    \penalty-\numexpr#1*100+50\relax
    \vskip0pt plus-#1\baselineskip
    \vskip#1\baselineskip
  \fi}

\long\def\blockquote#1\eol{%
  \emitsectglue{1}%
  \begingroup
    \raggedright\narrower\noindent #1%
    \smallskip
  \endgroup\noindent}

\subsubject
  The following subsubject will choose the first if's true-branch.

\subsubject
  But the following blockquote will not. Why is that?

\blockquote
  Be conservative in what you send, liberal in what you receive
\eol

\bye
```